# Simple Pass Thru cikernel Distorts Color Values

Tags: swift, cifilter, cikernel

I've written a rgbToHSV cikernel to convert the pixels in images; however, it is not working correctly.  I've narrowed it down to the fact that the RGB values are being distorted along the way.

To simplify my code, I've changed it to a simple pass through filter.

I've passed images of 1280 x 720 images that are all one color and then sampled pixel colors at position (100, 100) vbefore and after it passes through the cikernel.

Here are the results:

Red
before:pixelColor :: rgba : 1.0 : 0.0 : 0.0 : 1.0
after: pixelColor :: rgba : 1.0 : 0.07450980392156863 : 0.0 : 1.0

Green
before:pixelColor :: rgba : 0.0 : 1.0 : 0.0 : 1.0
after: pixelColor :: rgba : 0.0 : 0.984313725490196 : 0.0 : 1.0

Blue
before:pixelColor :: rgba : 0.0 : 0.0 : 1.0 : 1.0
after: pixelColor :: rgba : 0.0 : 0.1803921568627451 : 1.0 : 1.0

As you can see Red and Green are slightly distorted, but Blue is massively distorted.

I have saved the output files and checked the colors and the filter is definitely altering the colors.

Any insight into why a simple passthrough is altering the colors is greatly appreciated.

Simplified Pass Thru Filter:

```
kernel vec4 rgbToHsv( __sample rgb) {
  return rgb;
}
```

Here's the CIFilter that uses the cikernel:

```
class RgbToHsvFilter: CIFilter {
  @objc dynamic var inputImage: CIImage?

  
  private lazy var kernel: CIColorKernel? = {
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "RgbToHsv", ofType: "cikernel"),
      let code = try? String(contentsOfFile: path) else { fatalError("Failed to load RgbToHsv.cikernel from bundle") }
    let kernel = CIColorKernel(source: code)
    return kernel
  }()

  override public var outputImage: CIImage! {
    get {
      if let inputImage = self.inputImage {
        
        let args = [inputImage as AnyObject]
        return self.kernel?.apply(extent: inputImage.extent, arguments: args)
      } else {
        return nil
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Calling the Filter

```
    let rgbToHsvFilter = RgbToHsvFilter()
    let currentCI = CIImage(cgImage: colorImage!.cgImage!)
    rgbToHsvFilter.setValue(currentCI, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    
    if let hsvImage = rgbToHsvFilter.outputImage {
      if let image = cgImage(from: hsvImage) {
        let newImage = UIImage(cgImage: image as! CGImage)
        
        
        let _ = newImage.getPixelColor(pos: pixelPoint)
     
        //UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
      }
    }
  }
```

the getPixelColor method where the CGPoint is set to (100, 100).  I thought the issue might be occurring here as a possible misrepresentation in the print statement of the color coming out, but I checked the actual output images and filter is altering the image colors:

```
  func getPixelColor(pos: CGPoint) -> UIColor {
    
    let pixelData = self.cgImage!.dataProvider!.data
    let data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)
    
    let pixelInfo: Int = ((Int(self.size.width) * Int(pos.y)) + Int(pos.x)) * 4
    
    let r = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let g = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+1]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let b = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+2]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+3]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    
    print("pixelColor :: rgba : \(r) : \(g) : \(b) : \(a)")
    
    return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
  }
```

and cgImage (edited):

```
  func cgImage(from ciImage: CIImage) -> CGImage? {
      let context = CIContext(options: nil)
      return context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent)
  }
```

Comment: I think it's due to conversation issue `linear_to_srgb` or `srgb_to_linear`

Comment: As SPatel said, this might be due to gamma correction. Can you please show the implementation of the `cgImage(from: hsvImage)` method?

Comment: @FrankSchlegel edited.

Comment: Can you please try to create the `CGImage` with `createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent, colorSpace: CGColorspace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)!)` and see if this changes things?

Comment: I tried it with format: and the Blue image with the results below:format .RGBA8 which gave me the same results. @FrankSchlegel

Comment: `func cgImage(from ciImage: CIImage) -> CGImage? {


    let context = CIContext(options: nil)


    return context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent, format: .RGBA8, colorSpace: CGColorSpace.init(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)!)


    //return context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent)
}`

Comment: .RGBA8 which gave me the same results.
pixelColor :: rgba : 0.0 : 0.1803921568627451 : 1.0 : 1.0

Comment: .RGBA16
pixelColor :: rgba : 0.0 : 0.0 : 0.9372549019607843 : 0.17647058823529413

Comment: .RGBAf
pixelColor :: rgba : 0.027450980392156862 : 0.07450980392156863 : 0.9058823529411765 : 0.7372549019607844

Comment: .RGBAh
pixelColor :: rgba : 0.2235294117647059 : 0.6549019607843137 : 0.7450980392156863 : 0.19215686274509805

Comment: I've found that something in going from CIImage to UIImage is causing the color distortion.  The ciKernel has nothing to do with the problem.  I'm going to open another question that addresses this.

Answer (score 0):

So the CIContext is not properly initialized in method cgImage.

Here's the corrected method:

```
  func cgImage(from ciImage: CIImage) -> CGImage? {
    let context = CIContext(options: [CIContextOption.workingColorSpace: kCFNull!])
    return context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent, format: .RGBA8, colorSpace: CGColorSpace.init(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)!)
  }
```